# Apache virtual host not working correctly

Tags: apache, windows-7, xampp, virtualhost

I'm getting some strange behaviour on my local Windows 7 machine, which I am using to develop a website, when trying to access a specific virtual host on a xampp server.

I currently have seven vhosts on my apache server, and all but one work exactly as intended.

The `httpd-vhosts` entry for the site is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Work\pim4bim\buildSite"
    ServerName pim4bmbuild
    ServerAlias pim4bimbuild
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
    <Directory "C:\Work\pim4bim\buildSite">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have the `NameVirtualHost` line uncommented and have added the entry to my Windows hosts file.

The strange behaviour is that, when accessing the vhost on my Windows machine, it displays a page that doesn't actually exist, at best it could be a partial reading of a page, but this doesn't make sense. (It shows some text that exists on other pages, but none of these include *only* that text.)

However, when accessing the vhost from my Linux box, like I do all other of my vhosts, the site is operating correctly. While this is fine for development, I need to be able to access the vhost on my Windows machine for client demos and work away from home.

I have triple checked that my vhost and hosts entries are properly formatted, and changed the directory listing from backward to forward slashes and back again with no difference. I've also restarted Apache several times (and added new vhosts since this one) to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

When I load the page, my access log shows the following:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jun/2013:12:18:43 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 344 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jun/2013:12:18:43 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 849 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Are you sure that the name pim4bmbuild is resolving correctly on your Windows machine?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows, but on Linux you can do `host pim4bmbuild` and you'll get the IP address. Also: do you see the failing requests in your access-log file?

Comment: I did a `ping` for pim4bimbuild and it resolves to 127.0.0.1 - the same as set up in hosts file. I've also updated my question with the access logs.